# Replace the timeValue in a datetime insted of Add the time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime, datetimepicker

In a WPF Application, I have a `DateTimePicker`.
I save on a `DateTime` variable, the `DateTimePicker` value with a time.

```
dDate = DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value.Add(TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

This code is Ok when dDate is null, but, when i update the `DateTimePicker`, the `Time` is Added.

So,if my `DateTimePicker` is : 1/2/2013 with 01:20.

At the first :

```
dDate = DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value.Add(TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

All is ok, but, if i re-execute this line :

```
dDate = DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value.Add(TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

The dDate value will be : 1/2/2013 with 02:40.

Could anyone tell me how solve this problem please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to the `Date` property of the `DateTime`:

```
DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate.Value.Date.Add(
                                        TimePicker_Heure.Value.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

The `Date` property has `00:00:00` time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's ok with this :)